# On a closed manifold whose curvature is close to "hyperbolic"

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\Vol{Vol}$In 1.7 on p.224 of the following paper, there is a rigidity result for compact manifolds whose sectional curvature is almost $-1$.

[Gromov, M.. Manifolds of negative curvature. J. Differential Geometry 13 (1978), no. 2, 223-230.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-13/issue-2/Manifolds-of-negative-curvature/10.4310/jdg/1214434487.full)

**Statement:** Given $n \geq 4$ and $C>0$, there is an $\epsilon_0=\epsilon_0(n, C)>0$ so that
for any $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0$, if a compact
Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ satisfies $-1 \leq K \leq -1+\epsilon$ and the volume $\Vol(M,g) \leq C$, then it must admit a metric of constant negative sectional curvature.

The above result is mentioned as a standard application from the main "non-collapsing" result (in Sec 1.2 on p.223 of the above paper). Roughly speaking, under the above assumption the volume has a lower bound, and the diameter has an upper bound. However I could not figure out the proof of Statement.

Assume by contradiction, we have a sequence of $(M_i, g_i)$ whose curvature is $-1<K<-1+\epsilon_i$ and $\Vol(M_i, g_i) \leq C$, but each of $M_i$ does not admit a hyperbolic metric. then we may apply the $C^{1, \alpha}$ convergence theory of Cheeger-Gromov. Now we get a smooth manifold $N$ and diffeomorphisms $f_i: N \rightarrow M_i$ so that the pull back $f_i^{\ast} g_i$ converges to a $C^{1, \alpha}$ metric $h$ on $N$ under the $C^{1, \alpha}$ norm. Even if $\alpha$ could be $1$, the convergence is still weaker than $C^2$.

**Question:** Why is $(N, h)$ a hyperbolic metric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know two ways to complete the argument.

1. The lower curvature bound is preserved under GH convergence, and so is the upper curvature bound provided there is a lower bound on convexity radius. In the universal cover the convexity radius is infinite. So the universal cover converges to an Alexandrov space of curvature both $\ge -1$ and $\le -1$. Then  there is a rigidity result saying that the metric must be Riemannian and hyperbolic. For the latter one usually refers to an old paper of Alexandrov [Uber eine Verallgemeinerung der Riemannschen Geometrie, Schriften Forschungsinst. Math (1957), no. 1, 33–84]. I suspect this is what Gromov had in mind.
2. <strike>One can also use smoothing (e.g. by Ricci flow run for short time) to get control of the covariant derivatives of the curvature tensor in the sequence without changing curvature bound very much. This will ensure that the convergence is $C^\infty$, and so the limit is hyperbolic.</strike>

EDIT: I take back method 2, but wish to offer a variation on 1. Instead of quoting Alexandrov's paper, (which I must confess I have not read because my German is very poor), one can argue that in the limit there is a weak curvature tensor that satisfies the Einstein equation of the hyperbolic metric, and hence by a standard regularity argument the limiting metric is $C^\infty$, and because it has curvature $\ge -1$ and $\le -1$ in the comparison sense, it is hyperbolic. The weak curvature tensor argument can be extracted from [Convergence of Riemannian manifolds; Ricci and
$L^{n/2}$-curvature pinching
L. Zhiyong Gao
J. Differential Geom. 32(2): 349-381 (1990).](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-32/issue-2/Convergence-of-Riemannian-manifolds-Ricci-and-Lsp-n-2-curvature/10.4310/jdg/1214445311.full)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regarding the 2nd approach, I did tried before asking the question. Assume there is a sequence $(M_i, g_i)$ with the above assumption. there we may construct a sequence of flows $(M_i, g_i(t))$ on $[0, T]$. Then the bounds of covariant derivatives is like $\frac{C}{t}$ and $K(g_i(t)) \in [-1-ct, -1+\epsilon_i+ct]$. It seems that we can not take a sequence like $(M_i, g_i(t_i))$ with $t_i$ converging to zero. Instead we have to do it for a fix $t_o$. This will produce a limit flow $(N, h(t))$ where $t \in (0, T]$ with $K(h(t)) \in [-1-ct, -1+ct]$.

Comment: then I don't know why $h(0)$ can be defined and is hyperbolic. Did I miss sth?

Comment: @Bo_Y: maybe I am misremembering the flow part. Let me think this through.

Comment: Is $C^1$ convergence not enough to show that geodesic segments converge to geodesic segments strongly enough to use geodesic triangles to show the limit is hyperbolic?

Comment: Another approach is not to use the $C^{1,\alpha}$ convergence theory but the $W^{p,2}$ convergence theory, including the existence of harmonic coordinates (Anderson-Cheeger do this very nicely). I think that might suffice.

Comment: Sorry for my delay! Thanks to both of you for bringing new references. I sounds to me that Gao did not discuss the weak curvature explicitly in his work? In any case, I agree that some weak notion of curvature (bypassing the Alexandrov curvature) works on the limit since we have C^{1,1} convergence. I will try to figure out an argument following your suggestions.

Comment: @Bo_Y: p.360 says "from the proof of Theorem 0.1, the weak curvature tensor
of g is well defined and we have...".

Comment: @IgorBelegradek   Yes, I saw it but it seems it deals with $C^{1, \alpha}$ convergence away from the bubble. I did not see exactly the weak curvature defined. Back to sectional curvature pinching, I found Fukaya has another approach in Gromov's situation in his survey "Hausdorff convergence of Riemannian manifolds and its applications" (1990).  On p.198 Lemma 15.3 there he proved the limit is smooth by showing the limit metric is symmetric and its isometric group is a Lie group, then it is smooth as we write local coordinates $g_{ij}$ in terms of smooth data from this Lie group.

Comment: The regularity of limit seems to appear in many similar pinching problems. Another example is Berger's famous $\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon$ positive pinching (Ann. Inst. Fourier (Grenoble) (1983)). There he proves the limit is smooth by some comparison geometry and use diamater, cut locus and other stuff. I don't know French, not sure if his method is helpful to negative pinching.

Comment: @DeaneYang Following your suggestion. Using the $C^{1, \alpha}$ convergence, I think it holds that any sufficiently small geodesic triangle on the limit should have the same interior angle with that in the space form $K=-1$.  Is the metric smooth hyperbolic? Not sure how to go back to curvature. It sounds a special case of the rigdity result of Alexandrov mentiond by Igor.

Comment: @Bo_Y: you can read more about  the weak curvature tensor in Nikolaev's paper "Stability problems in a theorem of F. Schur".